# .htaccess url rewrite remove id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible with .htaccess to remove the parameter ID of the url & just show the text. Currently i have url like

Current URL

```
http://localhost/profile.php?profileid=4554
```

Rewrited with .htaccess

```
http://localhost/profileid-4554/My UserName
```

Needed URL

```
http://localhost/profileid/My UserName
```

In the above url, i want to remove the id 4554. My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^profileid-([0-9]+) profile?profileid=$1
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
index.php
<a href="directory/1">click</a>

detail.php
<?php 
echo $_GET['id'];
echo $_GET['page'];
 ?>

.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  detail.php?page=$1&id=$2    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask about `http://localhost/profileid-4554/My UserName`. I don't understand where you take `My username`. But the rest can be done by next

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} profileid=([^&]+)
RewriteRule profile.php /profileid-%1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?url=$1
```